# How can I install Grunt an any nitrous.io box

Tags: nitrousio

I am developing an python app on a Nitrous.io python box but I am using a grunt to build the front end. How can I install node, grunt and bower on a python box?

Answer (score 2):

Grunt requires Node.JS version `>=0.8.0` ([source](http://gruntjs.com/getting-started)), and currently [Nitrous.IO](https://www.nitrous.io/) only offers Node.JS on the Node.JS templates ([source](http://help.nitrous.io/box-interpreters-and-tools/)).

As a workaround, you may want to look into building your Python project on a Node.JS template using Nitrous.IO. Along with NPM and Node.JS, the template also includes Python 2.7.3, [pip](http://www.pip-installer.org/en/latest/), and [virtualenv](http://www.virtualenv.org/).

Comment: Yes, they're using ubuntu and it comes with python 2.7. But it might break when they switch to python 3.

Comment: Would running within virtualenv be a safe route? I'm not sure what scenarios you were suggesting that it may break in. A Python 3.x environment could be setup by running `virtualenv -p /usr/bin/python3.3 py3env` , followed by `source py3env/bin/activate`.

Comment: My app require python 2.7 and python 2.7 is available because the python 2.7 is the OS default python version. But any day the box OS can get an upgrade and might lose python 2.7.

Comment: Just run your projects within Virtualenv to ensure you are always using 2.7. Run `virtualenv -p /usr/bin/python2.7 py27`, followed by `source py27/bin/activate` to initialize Virtualenv with Python 2.7.